# How to Show Two table columns in a aspxgridview?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have tow tables in mssql server, Car & Weight.

Car has IDCar, Name, Username, Description columns.

And Weight has IDWeight, CarID, Name, Date, Weight columns.

I want to show Name of Car table in the first column of aspx gridview and show weight and date from Weight Table.

The Name is static, but everyday user must input date and weight for each car.

I wish it was clear about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a query with the `join` with both tables and get the desired result and then bind that result to the `gridview`. Your query can be like,

```
   Select c.Name,w.Weight,w.Date
   FROM 
       Car c LEFT Join Weight w
           ON c.CarID = w.CarID
```

---

**UPDATE**

Applied `left join` after the comment.[Left Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx) will give you all the car names from the `Car` table irrespective of if there are data present in the Weight table for that car or not.

To use the `Where` in join just use it as normal `where` clause.

```
    WHERE  
        w.Date = GETDATE()  //Change according your need
        AND w.Weight = 110  //Change according your need
```

[To read more about join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[To bind datatable to the Gridview read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the aspxgridview does not show anything when Weight Table has no data, I want to show Car names either there is no weight and date.

Comment: Does your car name come from the database ? Then you can apply the left join

Comment: Yes, Car table has data and Weight table has no data. Left join didn't work for me.

Comment: Really Thanks! I think it works! How can I use where in this left join? for example, I want to show only Today Date and Weight

Answer (score 0):

```
 select car.Name,weigth.weight,weigth.date from car
 inner join weight on car.carid=weigth.carid
```

you can add a filter to specifiy which item you want using where clause:

```
  where carid in ('xx','123','guid') and weight.weight between 100 and 200
```

Comment: You could have edited your already present answer. Please do that. And `Inner join` not going to solve the issue of the OP

Comment: to get arround weight issue you can use left join: 
left join weight on weight.carid is null or  weight.carid=car.carid